# Informatica services stops automatically

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have installed Informatica in Windows virtual machine. But the service gets stopped automatically. Even if start manually, it stops within 5-10 minutes.

How can I investigate this?

Comment: do you have enough CPU, RAM and Space? System parameters set? Have you checked Win 10 is compatible with your Infa? Also, could you please check catalina.log/node.log etc.

Comment: I've seen same issue some time ago. I've never been able to nail it, but my guess is it's due to resources, as @KoushikRoy mentioned here. Try checking catalina.out for more information and monitor the resource use carefuly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks into tomcat log. Which is there under logs folder in informatica installed location